# How to set path to matplotlib custom style?

Tags: python, matplotlib

As per matplotlib documentation:

"You can create custom styles and use them by calling style.use with the path or URL to the style sheet."

I tried:

```
plt.style.use('/usr/share/mygraph/mystyle.mplstyle')
```

but it is returning:

```
ValueError: '/usr/share/mygraph/mystyle.mplstyle' not found in the style library and input is not a valid URL or path. See `style.available` for list of available styles.
```

Could someone please help me on how to set the path right?

Is there is any other way how to achieve this?

I would like to distribute my custom style in rpm package so it would be tricky to put it in user's home dir.

Setting "MPLCONFIGDIR" environment variable would also work but I would like to avoid this.

Thanks for your help!

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
EDIT:

In my impetuosity I forgot to copy the file there. The output error about not valid URL confused me so I thought the whole path is not valid and focused on that. Shame on me!

Comment: `plt.style.use('file:///usr/share/mygraph/mystyle.mplstyle')` should work.

Comment: Thanks for your response! It worked, however it worked also the way I tried it before but in my impetuosity I forgot to copy the file there. The output error about not valid URL confused me so I thought the whole path is not valid and focused on that. Shame on me! But again, thanks for your quick reply...

Comment: Would you consider closing that post, then?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it can be useful to future readers to know that there is also the possibility of changing the style folder (you can get the current folder with `matplotlib.get_configdir()`). According to [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/introductory/customizing.html#customizing-with-style-sheets):

> You also can change the directory where Matplotlib looks for the
> stylelib/ folder by setting the [MPLCONFIGDIR](https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/faq/environment_variables_faq.html#envvar-MPLCONFIGDIR) environment variable, [see
> matplotlib configuration and cache directory locations](https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/faq/troubleshooting_faq.html#locating-matplotlib-config-dir).